AWS API Gateway and CORS issues
I have an AWS API Gateway URL (https://mhw8mm294k.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/saveImage) that has a GET, POST, and OPTIONS method. CORS is enabled on the resource. When I use a browser (GET) or Postman (POST) it works.. In the VUE code I am using AXIOS to do a post. This always fails with a CORS error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mhw8mm294k.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/saveImage' from origin 'https://mikesmilkbottles.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


The CORS settings on the API Gateway are as follows: 

The VUE code that does the post sends a x-www-form-urlencoded (form) for the lambda to process. Note that the request never passes the Gateway when used in the code. It does with Postman.


    const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

  }
};


async getImage() {

     
      let image = this.$refs.image.files[0];
      let url = this.$refs.url.value;
      let id =this.$refs.id.value;
      let name = this.$refs.name.value;
      let city = this.$refs.city.value;
      let county = this.$refs.county.value;
      let state = this.$refs.state.value;
      let cost = this.$refs.cost.value;
      let wanted = this.$refs.wanted.value;
      // alert(id)
      // alert(this.$refs.id.value)
      if (image) {
        // alert("here")
        let data = new FormData();
        // alert(document.getElementById("id"))
        data.append('id', id);
        data.append('image', image);
        data.append("name",name);
        data.append("city",city);
        data.append("county",county);
        data.append("state",state);
        data.append("cost",cost);
        data.append("wanted",wanted);
        data.append("url",url);

        // send fetch along with cookies

        await this.$http.post("https://mhw8mm294k.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/saveImage",data,config).then(response =>{
          // console.log("status: " +response.data)
          if(response.status === 200){
            this.mb = MilkBottle.convertObject(response.data.body)
            // console.log(this.mb)
          }
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
          this.$emit("hasServerError");
        })
       



      }
      this.$refs.image.value = "";

    }


Further information can be found here:
CORS error question
Any and all ideas, thoughts, and possible solutions are greatly appreciated. In fact if you read this entire question I appreciated that too (lol).
Thanks in advance.
